# Postgres: check if array field contains a jsonb value with a specific property?

Tags: postgresql

Here's an example setup:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id text NOT NULL,
    pets jsonb[] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users (id, pets) values ('random-id', array[
    '{"name": "Spot", "toys": [{"color": "red"}, {"color": "blue"}]}',
    '{"name": "Zeus", "toys": [{"color": "purple"}, {"color": "red"}]}'
]::jsonb[]);
```

Example query:
How do I find ids of all users with at least one pet with at least one red toy?

Comment: Why do you use `jsonb[]` instead of `jsonb` simply? Json does support arrays, an array of jsons is an unnecessary complication. With this approach you probably have to `unnest` the table first.

Comment: `jsonb[]` almost never makes sense. It's better  to use `jsonb` and store a JSON array in it (not an array of jsonb)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't choose the schema of the DB when it was created! Is there a way to do it with the current schema?

edit: I'm looking into the `unnest` function... that seems useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema is... problematic. You should really use `jsonb` instead of `jsonb[]` since json supports arrays out of the box.

Anyway, if the schema is as it is, then you can utilize something like this:

```sql
select distinct tmp2.id
from (
    select
        tmp1.id,
        jsonb_array_elements(tmp1.pets->'toys') as toys
    from (
        select
            id,
            unnest(pets) as pets
        from users
    ) tmp1
) tmp2
where jsonb_extract_path_text(tmp2.toys, 'color') = 'red'
```

(it can be probably written in a more readable way by utilizing `with` instead of nesting selects)

**Explanation:**

`unnest` will turn an internal array into separate rows.

`jsonb_array_elements` does the same thing, except it operates on jsonb arrays (we have to unwrap the internal `toys` arrays as well).

`jsonb_extract_path_text` retrieves the internal text stored under key.

Note that the query assumes the specific format you have. I didn't test the query against other json variants.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works.

Following up, is there a way to modify this query to change all the red colors to blue?

Comment: @EricChen sure, you just need to change `'red'` string at the end to `'blue'`.

Comment: Oh, I meant instead of just SELECT-ing the user ids, we UPDATE the table by changing all 'red' values to 'blue'.

Comment: @freakish How would I do it if the column was just `jsonb`?